# ASP.NET Core MVC view and environment specific Javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

Today I started to add some client side Javascript code, like a nice date picker or some collapsing modals to my ASP.NET Core MVC WebApp.
I don't need all this settings on initial stuff in each view, so on my opinion the cleanest way is to define for each view a own js file.
**First** would I like to know, if this is the right way to do stuff like this? Or just take a big .js file, give each element a unique id and work over that?

So I was looking for achieving this in a nice way. But I only found partial solutions and build out of this my own.

In my `wwwroot/js` folder I'm reflecting the structure of the `Views` folder.
Like: `Views/Home/Index` => `wwwroot/js/home/index.js`
To minimize the `.js` I just append a entry to the `bundleconfig.json` like:

```
{
 " outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/home/index.min.js",
  "inputFiles": [
  "wwwroot/js/home/index.js"
],
  // Optionally specify minification options
  "minify": {
  "enabled": true,
  "renameLocals": true
},
  // Optionally generate .map file
  "sourceMap": false
}
```

and get a `wwwroot/js/home/index.min.js`.
To load the right .js file I use the following code in my `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@if (File.Exists($"wwwroot/js/{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]}/{ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]}.min.js"))    
{
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower()/@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower()@{}.js"></script>
}
```

To determine the right *environment* I use the predefined `Development` and `Staging,Production` tags.

To the big **second** question: Would you do this the same way, or do you have a better approach for solving this?