# ASP.NET Core - Filling views with data incrementally

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a .Net Core application and I have come to part in my code where I need to add data incrementally based on user clicks. First I have a table with elements. Once any element is clicked I need to go and fetch some data from my Entity Framework implementation and based on what I get I should "post" that to the view in a table format.

Then further on the user can click on an element in that new table, and based on the click I need to draw a map with a pointer on it.

I am wondering what is good practice in .Net Core regarding a site like this?

Currently I have a similar-ish view, however only with a single table and a `partialView`. They way that is implemented is using my `site.js` to register clicks and HTML elements with `data-url`s to run my controller methods. Is this the best or most optimal method or is there a smarter way? I really just want to know what types of solutions there are..

I talked with some friends who mentioned they would create a `<script></script>` section inside their HTML to perform actions like this. I would not nescesarily consider this a best practice for read-ability for code and for fastest possible responses, but I am all ears for other methods for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dynamic content**

For my opinion the nicest way to add dynamic html code is

- Create `GET` actions in the according controller for getting rendered html-code from partial views (Here you can decide what you want to return)
- When some item of your table is clicked, request this actions(with ajax) with the according parameters and return the rendered html data
- Insert the HTML with jQuery

*Example:*

*The GET Action*

```
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
public async Task<IActionResult> NewStamp(string date, string recentProject)
{

    // Do work with paramters and evaluate right html-code

    return PartialView("_CollectionPartial", new ViewModel(date, recentProject));
}
```

*The HTML-Button*

```
<button asp-controller="Stamps" asp-area="WorkTime" asp-action="NewStamp" id="addStamp" type="button" class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
</button>
```

*The ajax-request*

```
$.ajax({
        url: this.formAction,
        data: "date=" + date.format("HH:mm") + "&recentProject=" + recentProject,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#id').append(html);
```

**Handling .js files**

Yesterday I asked a similar question without effort.
But I built my own solution, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244115/asp-net-core-mvc-view-and-environment-specific-javascript-file).